# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IOrderedEnumerable<DateTime>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have gallery in my project and I want to group it by their upload date for example if page = 1 it should show 2019/1/2 pictures and if page = 2 it should show 2019/1/4 pictures but I can't do it. It says I can't select `Dates[Page - 1]`.

```
public IEnumerable<GalleryPictures> GetGalleryByDates(int Page)
{
    var AllGalleryPictures = GetAllGalleryPictures();
    var Dates = AllGalleryPictures.Select(p => p.UploadDate).ToList().Distinct().OrderByDescending(p=>p);
    return AllGalleryPictures.Where(p => p.UploadDate == Dates[Page - 1]);

}
```

Comment: Add `ToList` after `Select`

Comment: Since you only need one date you can do `var date = AllGalleryPictures.Select(p => p.UploadDate).Distinct().OrderByDescending(p=>p).Skip(Page - 1).FirstOrDefault();` and use that.  Note that this gives the default value when there are fewer than `Page` items, whereas what you're doing would result in an index out of range exception with the `ToList` moved to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your issue:

```
var Dates = AllGalleryPictures.Select(p => p.UploadDate).Distinct().OrderByDescending(p=>p).ToList();
```

Also read more about [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses `ToList`, which [materialises the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution) - that is, it allocates a List and executes the query expression for each possible element in the sequence.

In your case this is unlikely to cause a significant performance penalty, but if you are writing large and complex queries you *may* impact performance by making the application do lots of work to create result objects that will never be used.

To mitigate this, you can use [`ElementAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat) to access only the element you actually want. However do note that you have already made this irrelevant in your code example by calling ToList on the preceding line.